# cout and String concatenation

Tags: c++, iostream, string-concatenation

I was just reviewing my C++. I tried to do this:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void printStuff(int x);

int main() {
    printStuff(10);
    return 0;
}

void printStuff(int x) {
    cout << "My favorite number is " + x << endl;
}
```

The problem happens in the `printStuff` function. When I run it, the first 10 characters from "My favorite number is ", is omitted from the output. The output is "e number is ". The number does not even show up.

The way to fix this is to do

```
void printStuff(int x) {
    cout << "My favorite number is " << x << endl;
}
```

I am wondering what the computer/compiler is doing behind the scenes.

Answer (score 11):

The + overloaded operator in this case is not concatenating any string since x is an integer. The output is moved by rvalue times in this case. So the first 10 characters are not printed. Check [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator+/) reference.

if you will write

```
cout << "My favorite number is " + std::to_string(x) << endl;
```

it will work

Answer (score 4):

It's simple pointer arithmetic. The string literal is an array or `char`s and will be presented as a pointer. You add 10 to the pointer telling you want to output starting from the 11th character.

There is no + operator that would convert a number into a string and concatenate it to a char array.

Answer (score 1):

adding or incrementing a string doesn't increment the value it contains but it's address:

- it's not problem of msvc 2015 or cout but instead it's moving in memory back/forward:
  to prove to you that cout is innocent:

  ```
  #include <iostream>
  using std::cout;
  using std::endl;

  int main() 
  {

      char* str = "My favorite number is ";
      int a = 10;

      for(int i(0); i < strlen(str); i++)
      std::cout << str + i << std::endl;

      char* ptrTxt = "Hello";
      while(strlen(ptrTxt++))
          std::cout << ptrTxt << std::endl;

      // proving that cout is innocent:

      char* str2 = str + 10; // copying from element 10 to the end of str to stre. like strncpy()
      std::cout << str2 << std::endl; // cout prints what is exactly in str2

     return 0;
  }
  ```